# Multiple angular directives for slick slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slick.js

I need some assistance getting Ken Wheeler slick.js to work in angular implementation.

I read a similar thread here where someone had an issue and I am able to implement that solution. But it only partly helped..

I want the display 2 sliders, where 1 has the image and the other has information based on the image. This requires 2 elements of different names and the instance of each element needs to communicate with the other.

I'm thinking this requires 2 directives that need the share the same scope. I created an parent directive and 2 child directives with the requirement to access the parent directive.

When I test the file, angular issues a compile error 
"Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$compile/ctreq?p0=slickSlider&p1=infoSlider

From the doc, the infoSlider cannot see the slickSlider controller. But I do not see why. If I strip out the controller reference and the html config it works.

Any direction will be appreciated thanks.

```
.directive('slickSlider', function(){


    return{


            controller:function($scope){this.scope=$scope;}


    };  
})
.directive('navSlider', function($timeout){


    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require:'^slickSlider',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs,slickSlider) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $(element).slick(scope.$eval(attrs.navSlider));
                },50)
        }

    };
})
.directive('infoSlider', function($timeout){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require:'^slickSlider',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs,slickSlider) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $(element).slick(scope.$eval(attrs.infoSlider));
                },50)
            }

    };
})

<div nav-slider ="{
                centerPadding: '40px',
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2,
                sNavFor: '.slider-for',
                dots: true,
                centerMode: true,
                focusOnSelect: true
            }" >
            <div class="slider-nav" ng-repeat="category in catProducts">

                   <div><img src="{{category.placehldr}}" /></div>     


            </div><br />        
    <div info-slider ="{
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: false,
                fade: true,
                asNavFor: '.slider-nav'

            }" >
            <div class="slider-for" ng-repeat="category in catProducts|orderBy:category.productID">

                   <div><img src="{{category.placehldr}}" /></div>     


            </div>
```

Comment: I can't see the `slick-slider` directive anywhere in your markup?

Comment: @jjnezz the directive is the first directive  notation, slickSlider.

Comment: I said "in your markup" not "in your JavaScript". There isn't a `slick-slider` attribute on any of your HTML elements or a `slick-slider` element.

Comment: @jjenzz.. Got you.. This problem wore me out.. I changed the requirement to the existing controller and the second slideshow did render. Last thing now is to bind changes made from master slideshow to effect the second.